# How to use extract shortcode in loop?

Tags: php, slider, wordpress, shortcode

Actually I need to gallery in any new post so i use shortcode for making gallery for every new post. I use images and videos in slider. problem is that I have custom html slider need to convert dynamic. so how to extract shortcode and use images and videos in `<li></li>`tag?

Comment: Getting videos is a difficult method, you would need to find each instance of youtube in content. As far as galleries go that is easy, you can use [`get_post_gallery_images()` Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery_images) which has an example of what you're looking to do.

Comment: i created custom meta box for uploading images through plugin. whose automatically generate shortcode for images. but now i confuse how to use shortcode in wordpress loop to implement in html slider.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this to use a shortcode in a php template:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[YOURSHORTCODE]'); ?>
```